# Copy three columns from one database table to another

Tags: iphone, sqlite

I'm updating an iPhone app with a SQLite3 database. The user's have a database on their phone currently, and I need to update three of the columns with new data (stored in a separate database) if the id of the rows match.

I've been able to attach the two tables and copy an entire table, but not only three columns.

```
database1
table1
id, col1, col2, col3, col4

database2
table1
id, col1, col2, col3, col4
```

I want to copy col1, col2, & col3 (not col4) from database1, table1 to database2, table1 if the ids match.

Comment: how have you opened connection to two separate databases ? I really wonder if a single query can copy data from one SQLIte3 db and insert into another. Are you using some tool ?

Comment: Since doing this seems impossible (at least easily), I've just separated the table into "user data" and "app data". That will be easier in the long run and should have been done since day one anyway.

Comment: I asked you the question about opening the separate connection because I did the same as what you are asking but that was using an external tool called SQLiteManager.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a query along the following lines:

```
//Select the database, table and table values
SELECT INTO 'db2.table2' (field1, field2, field3)
VALUES
//Insert data into second database using nested SQL
(SELECT * FROM 'db1.table1' (field1, field2, field3) WHERE field1 = 1)
```

Hope this helps (and works for you) :)